# Which Chromium versions are supported by Cypress

Tags: cypress

the initial question is described in headline :)
The Problem is, my Angular app should run on an embedded system with a Chromium of version 59. So it makes sence to run intgration tests of this app with Cypress and the mentioned Chromium version. But Cypress won't start this browser to run the tests. I tried the following versions of Chromium:
Case 1: [Win_464638_chrome-win32.zip](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Win%2F464638%2Fchrome-win32.zip?generation=1492133531425437&alt=media) - I copied this zip content to  `c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\chrome-win-32`
Case 2: [Win_x64_464638_chrome-win32.zip](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Win_x64%2F464638%2Fchrome-win32.zip?generation=1492133913210486&alt=media) - I copied this zip content to  `c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\chrome-win-32`
Case 3: [Win_464638_mini_installer.exe](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Win%2F464638%2Fmini_installer.exe?generation=1492133555621991&alt=media) - I installed Chromium and run cmd `mklink /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\chrome-win32\" "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Chromium\Application"`
Case 4: [Win_x64_464638_mini_installer.exe](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Win_x64%2F464638%2Fmini_installer.exe?generation=1492133937948754&alt=media) - I installed Chromium and run cmd `mklink /D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\chrome-win32\" "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Chromium\Application"`

All browsers are starting, if I click on chrome.exe. Chromium is also find by Cypress, which I can select at the Cypress UI. But finally, if I run my test, the runner doesn't open the mentioned Chromium browser.

Hint: If I use a Chromium version from [this page](https://chromium.cypress.io/), everything works fine...but there is no version 59 or any older release of Chromium.

These are the trace logs:
Cypress trace for case 1 and 2 (relevant lines):

```html
2020-04-10T11:03:30.005Z cypress:launcher launching browser { browser: { displayName: 'Chromium', name: 'chromium', family: 'chromium', channel: 'stable', version: '59.0.3071.0', path: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\chrome-win32\\chrome.exe', majorVersion: 59, info: undefined, custom: undefined, warning: undefined, isChosen: true, isHeaded: true, isHeadless: false }, url: 'about:blank' }
2020-04-10T11:03:30.005Z cypress:launcher spawning browser with args { args: [ 'about:blank', '--test-type', '--ignore-certificate-errors', '--start-maximized', '--silent-debugger-extension-api', '--no-default-browser-check', '--no-first-run', '--noerrdialogs', '--enable-fixed-layout', '--disable-popup-blocking', '--disable-password-generation', '--disable-save-password-bubble', '--disable-single-click-autofill', '--disable-prompt-on-repos', '--disable-background-timer-throttling', '--disable-renderer-backgrounding', '--disable-renderer-throttling', '--disable-restore-session-state', '--disable-translate', '--disable-new-profile-management', '--disable-new-avatar-menu', '--allow-insecure-localhost', '--reduce-security-for-testing', '--enable-automation', '--disable-device-discovery-notifications', '--disable-infobars', '--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required', '--disable-site-isolation-trials', '--metrics-recording-only', '--disable-prompt-on-repost', '--disable-hang-monitor', '--disable-sync', '--disable-web-resources', '--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update', '--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection', '--disable-client-side-phishing-detection', '--disable-component-update', '--disable-default-apps', '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream', '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream', '--disable-ipc-flooding-protection', '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-window', '--disable-breakpad', '--password-store=basic', '--use-mock-keychain', '--proxy-server=http://localhost:51321', '--remote-debugging-port=51325', '--remote-debugging-address=127.0.0.1', '--load-extension=C:\\Users\\fs\\AppData\\Roaming\\Cypress\\cy\\production\\browsers\\chromium-stable\\interactive\\CypressExtension,C:\\Users\\fs\\AppData\\Local\\Cypress\\Cache\\4.3.0\\Cypress\\resources\\app\\packages\\extension\\theme', '--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\fs\\AppData\\Roaming\\Cypress\\cy\\production\\browsers\\chromium-stable\\interactive', '--disk-cache-dir=C:\\Users\\fs\\AppData\\Roaming\\Cypress\\cy\\production\\browsers\\chromium-stable\\interactive\\CypressCache' ] }
2020-04-10T11:03:30.023Z cypress:server:browsers:chrome connecting to Chrome remote interface at random port 51325
2020-04-10T11:03:30.023Z cypress:server:protocol Getting WS connection to CRI on port 51325
2020-04-10T11:03:30.216Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [16864:16980:0410/130330.224:ERROR:google_update_settings.cc(260)] Failed opening key Software\Chromium to set usagestats; result: 5
2020-04-10T11:03:30.227Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [16864:16856:0410/130330.236:ERROR:data_pack.cc(209)] Bad data pack version: got 5, expected 4

[16864:16856:0410/130330.236:ERROR:browser_theme_pack.cc(624)] Failed to load theme data pack.
2020-04-10T11:03:30.231Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [16864:16984:0410/130330.239:ERROR:web_database_backend.cc(113)] Cannot initialize the web database: 2
2020-04-10T11:03:30.279Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [0410/130330.288:ERROR:process_info.cc(631)] range at 0x1c0e457a00000000, size 0x1fe fully unreadable
2020-04-10T11:03:30.280Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [0410/130330.289:ERROR:process_info.cc(631)] range at 0x1c0e459a00000000, size 0x1fe fully unreadable

[0410/130330.289:ERROR:process_info.cc(631)] range at 0x1c0e459c00000000, size 0x1fe fully unreadable
2020-04-10T11:03:30.998Z cypress:launcher chromium exited: { code: 3221225477, signal: null }
2020-04-10T11:03:31.026Z cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 0, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51325 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) { errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 51325 } }
2020-04-10T11:03:32.127Z cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 1, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51325 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) { errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 51325 } }
2020-04-10T11:03:33.230Z cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 2, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51325 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) { errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 51325 } }
2020-04-10T11:03:34.332Z cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 3, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51325 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) { errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 51325 } }
2020-04-10T11:03:35.436Z cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 4, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51325 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) { errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 51325 } }
```

Cypress trace for case 3 and 4 (relevant lines):

```html
2020-04-10T11:08:58.637Z cypress:launcher launching browser { browser: { displayName: 'Chromium', name: 'chromium', family: 'chromium', channel: 'stable', version: '59.0.3071.0', path: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\chrome-win32\\chrome.exe', majorVersion: 59, info: undefined, custom: undefined, warning: undefined, isChosen: true, isHeaded: true, isHeadless: false }, url: 'about:blank' }
2020-04-10T11:08:58.637Z cypress:launcher spawning browser with args { args: [ 'about:blank', '--test-type', '--ignore-certificate-errors', '--start-maximized', '--silent-debugger-extension-api', '--no-default-browser-check', '--no-first-run', '--noerrdialogs', '--enable-fixed-layout', '--disable-popup-blocking', '--disable-password-generation', '--disable-save-password-bubble', '--disable-single-click-autofill', '--disable-prompt-on-repos', '--disable-background-timer-throttling', '--disable-renderer-backgrounding', '--disable-renderer-throttling', '--disable-restore-session-state', '--disable-translate', '--disable-new-profile-management', '--disable-new-avatar-menu', '--allow-insecure-localhost', '--reduce-security-for-testing', '--enable-automation', '--disable-device-discovery-notifications', '--disable-infobars', '--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required', '--disable-site-isolation-trials', '--metrics-recording-only', '--disable-prompt-on-repost', '--disable-hang-monitor', '--disable-sync', '--disable-web-resources', '--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update', '--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection', '--disable-client-side-phishing-detection', '--disable-component-update', '--disable-default-apps', '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream', '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream', '--disable-ipc-flooding-protection', '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-window', '--disable-breakpad', '--password-store=basic', '--use-mock-keychain', '--proxy-server=http://localhost:51647', '--remote-debugging-port=51652', '--remote-debugging-address=127.0.0.1', '--load-extension=C:\\Users\\fs\\AppData\\Roaming\\Cypress\\cy\\production\\browsers\\chromium-stable\\interactive\\CypressExtension,C:\\Users\\fs\\AppData\\Local\\Cypress\\Cache\\4.3.0\\Cypress\\resources\\app\\packages\\extension\\theme', '--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\fs\\AppData\\Roaming\\Cypress\\cy\\production\\browsers\\chromium-stable\\interactive', '--disk-cache-dir=C:\\Users\\fs\\AppData\\Roaming\\Cypress\\cy\\production\\browsers\\chromium-stable\\interactive\\CypressCache' ] }
2020-04-10T11:08:58.657Z cypress:server:browsers:chrome connecting to Chrome remote interface at random port 51652
2020-04-10T11:08:58.658Z cypress:server:protocol Getting WS connection to CRI on port 51652
2020-04-10T11:08:58.825Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [0410/130858.825:ERROR:sandbox_policy_base.cc(379)] Failed to add sandbox rule. error = 2, subsystem = 0, semantics = 1, pattern = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\chrome-win32\*.pdb'
2020-04-10T11:08:58.829Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [0410/130858.830:ERROR:sandbox_policy_base.cc(379)] Failed to add sandbox rule. error = 2, subsystem = 0, semantics = 1, pattern = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\chrome-win32\*.pdb'
2020-04-10T11:08:58.831Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [0410/130858.831:ERROR:sandbox_policy_base.cc(379)] Failed to add sandbox rule. error = 2, subsystem = 0, semantics = 1, pattern = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\chrome-win32\*.pdb'
2020-04-10T11:08:58.833Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [0410/130858.833:ERROR:sandbox_policy_base.cc(379)] Failed to add sandbox rule. error = 2, subsystem = 0, semantics = 1, pattern = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\chrome-win32\*.pdb'
2020-04-10T11:08:58.834Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [15892:15240:0410/130858.834:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Failed to launch GPU process.

[15892:15944:0410/130858.834:ERROR:google_update_settings.cc(260)] Failed opening key Software\Chromium to set usagestats; result: 5
2020-04-10T11:08:58.847Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [15892:14144:0410/130858.847:ERROR:data_pack.cc(209)] Bad data pack version: got 5, expected 4

[15892:14144:0410/130858.847:ERROR:browser_theme_pack.cc(624)] Failed to load theme data pack.
2020-04-10T11:08:58.849Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [15892:15976:0410/130858.850:ERROR:web_database_backend.cc(113)] Cannot initialize the web database: 2
2020-04-10T11:08:58.901Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [0410/130858.902:ERROR:process_info.cc(631)] range at 0x9dc0457a00000000, size 0x1ec fully unreadable
2020-04-10T11:08:58.914Z cypress:launcher chromium stderr: [0410/130858.914:ERROR:process_info.cc(631)] range at 0x9dc0459a00000000, size 0x1ec fully unreadable

[0410/130858.914:ERROR:process_info.cc(631)] range at 0x9dc0459c00000000, size 0x1ec fully unreadable
2020-04-10T11:08:59.597Z cypress:launcher chromium exited: { code: 3221225477, signal: null }
2020-04-10T11:08:59.660Z cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 0, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51652 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) { errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 51652 } }
2020-04-10T11:09:00.762Z cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 1, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51652 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) { errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 51652 } }
2020-04-10T11:09:01.866Z cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 2, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51652 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) { errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 51652 } }
2020-04-10T11:09:02.969Z cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 3, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:51652 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14) { errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 51652 } }
```

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this? I'm now in a very similar situation.

Comment: Yes, don't know anymore where I found the answer, but Chromium versions <64 are not supported by Cypress